# ThreeJS: Unreal Bloom render pass removes my meshes. What am I doing wrong here?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm still pretty new to Three and I love it but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here.

Code in this gist: https://gist.github.com/TheeBryanWhite/a7a2041fc8848a0ba449897883c43bdc

The first render does what it's supposed to do. It renders the horizontal and vertical lines. But then the second pass runs, which is supposed be a a render pass for the Unreal Bloom effect but nothing renders to the canvas. It's just blank. If I log the scene, I can see the meshes but the screen is just blank.

Thoughts?

Comment: The only thing I notice is that you're importing `BloomEffect` instead of `UnrealBloomPass`. Did you rename all references to `UnrealBloomPass` inside that file? It has the constructor, and some vectors that you might have missed. Also, [the official example](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_postprocessing_unreal_bloom.html#L36-L38) imports the post-processing classes separately. Did you merge all three classes into a single "postprocessing" file?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, BloomEffect is the name for UnrealBloomPass in this particular postprocessing package. The ThreeJS react library is a little different than the regular one. If that were the case, wouldn't it throw an error in the console if I had the name wrong?

Comment: Oh, it's impossible to tell what could be wrong without a live example, then. At this point you're no longer using the official "three.js" library, but someone's modified version. I recommend you use [the official Three.js files](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/jsm/postprocessing/UnrealBloomPass.js) for help with the `[three.js]` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have it figured out. I didn't have tbe syntax quite right for the postprocessing package I was using: https://www.npmjs.com/package/postprocessing

In my code I was setting up the composer like this:

```
setupComposer() {
    this.composer = new EffectComposer( this.renderer )
    this.composer.addPass( this.renderScene )
    this.composer.addPass( this.bloomPass )
}
```

when it should have been like this:

```
setupComposer() {
    this.composer = new EffectComposer( this.renderer )
    this.composer.addPass( new RenderPass(this.scene, this.camera) )
    this.composer.addPass( new EffectPass(this.camera, this.bloomPass ) )
}
```